# Android high memory usage when uploading a bitmap to server (100MB)

Tags: android, bitmap, heap-memory

I am trying to solve my problem that sometimes causes OutOfMemoryException. I am simply uploading a bitmap to server and then exiting activity. I've tried to recycle my bitmaps but the frag is still somehow big. This is my code:

```
private class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewEvent.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading data...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }


    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        if (bitmaps[0] == null)
            return null;
        setProgress(0);

        Bitmap bitmap = bitmaps[0];
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // convert Bitmap to ByteArrayOutputStream
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()); // convert ByteArrayOutputStream to ByteArrayInputStream
        bitmap.recycle();
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "my server"); // server

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            reqEntity.addPart("fileToUpload",
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg", in);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            Log.i("TAG", "request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (response != null)
                    try {
                        response1 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        response1 = response1.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
                        Log.i("TAG", "response " + response1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            } finally {

            }
        } finally {

        }

        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        uploadJSON();
    }
}
```

Comment: `uploading a bitmap to server`. Please tell where this bitmap comes from. Won't you rather upload a file? You are NOT uploading a Bitmap to your server. You are uploading a PNG image to your server. And you tell your server that is is a .jpg.

Comment: My bitmap comes from ImageView where I post it from camera or gallery

Comment: In both cases it can be be that you load a jpg file as Bitmap in an ImageView. And then you extract again a Bitmap from an ImageView?  Certainly if you choose from Gallery an existing file better use that file. If you are going to upload you could better upload that file. Makes life much easier. And certainly no out of memory errors. How do you extract a bitmap from an imageview?

Comment: I agree with @greenapps. Extracting image from Bitmap is meaningless in your situation.

Comment: well, i found this an easy solution. Now I am facing another problem and that is that the data is sometimes null. (Happens on Nexus mostly)

Answer (score 0):

**bitmap.compress** may cause OOM error. Try using **BitmapFactory.decodeStream** with **BitmapFactory.Options**

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.outHeight=400;
options.outWidth=600;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet so I can get the idea ?

Comment: I edited my answer. There are a lot of options. Choose them which are suitable for you.(options.inSampleSize is good for start to try)

Comment: OP will still need `bitmap.compress`. And if OP reads really from a FileInputStream (which he did not tell as much) this is still a bad solution.

Comment: @greenapps you are right but, after scaling the original image, bitmap.compress should not raise OOM error.